# PHP Soap and REST based service best practise

Tags: php, web-services, rest, soap

I am working on a library where I would like to implement a Soap and a REST based client letting the library user decide between Soap or REST.

My question is; the service that I am consuming has a ton of operations/functions to call, like Debtor_GetAll, Debtor_Create, Debtor_Update, Debtor_Find_By_Name and so forth.

Should I represent each operation/function that the service offers as a method in an interface like this

```
interface iService
{
public function Debtor_Get_All();
public function Debtor_Create($params);
public function Debtor_Update($params);
public function Debtor_Find_By_name($name);
}
```

or should I try to abstract from the service and implement something like

```
interface iService
{
public function get( $debtor_id );
public function post( $params );
public function put( $params );
}
```

in order for Soap and REST to adhere to the same "vocabulary"? The first option gives me a ton of methods to implement, each doing a unique job. The second options gives me less methods to implement but more complex logic per method. More complex since the get() method would have to handle both Debtor_Get_All as well as Debtor_Find_By_Name.

The Soap client would the implement the interface and take care of all the Soap based communication, and the REST based client would do the same.

But what is the best option between the two, and is there a third or forth I haven't come across yet?

*Possible solution*

```
namespace Services;

interface iService
{}

namespace Services;

class BaseService
{}

namespace Services\Soap;

class Debtor extends BaseService implements iService
{}

class Invoice extends BaseService implements iService
{}

namespace Services\REST;

class Debtor extends BaseService implements iService
{}

class Invoice extends BaseService implements iService
{}
```

Comment: The interface your app uses should not change, only the underlying transport. So to that end, you are on the right track with your first interface, which would be responsible for taking the request from the application, and passing it through to either your soap or rest client

Comment: Lots of small interfaces with clearly defined operations are going to be easier to use than a generic super operation which does things differently depending on what data is passed. Smaller operations are often easier to maintain and extend as well. The downside is a lot more development. Doing both REST and SOAP seems like overkill though.

Comment: @Namphibian the web service I consume in my library offers both options, REST and Soap, I know it's an overkill, but also challenging

Comment: Lol good I like to see a man earn his striped by struggling. Never ever rob someone the privilege of struggle.Good luck with that. I would suggest you look at microservices architecture and service orchestration to understand the long term fruit of small services vs large services.

Comment: @Namphibian yeah, I know, but I am doing this for fun. I took a look at http://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html describing the microservice architecture, I agree this sounds like the sane approach. I added some example code, not sure if this is correct yet, but Ill give it a go.